# Array of Objects Filter Optimization

Tags: ecmascript-6

I am not sure what the most efficient solution for solving this problem is, I can solve it inefficiently using loops but wish to optimise my code a bit and find a more elegant solution using ES6 and above: I have an array of javascript objects with integers stored in each of the underscore variables:

```
var netAggregatedPosition=[];

function createAggregate(){
netAggregatedPosition.push({"2017_Q1":_2017Q1});
netAggregatedPosition.push({"2017_Q2":_2017Q2});
netAggregatedPosition.push({"2017_Q3":_2017Q3});
netAggregatedPosition.push({"2017_Q4":_2017Q4});
netAggregatedPosition.push({"2018_Q1":_2018Q1});
netAggregatedPosition.push({"2018_Q2":_2018Q2});
netAggregatedPosition.push({"2018_Q3":_2018Q3});
netAggregatedPosition.push({"2018_Q4":_2018Q4});
}

var d;
```

I then have a variable "d" that will be dynamically changing as a user hovers over an onscreen element continuously updating d with the relevant string "2018_Q2" etc, which represents the element they are hovering over. What is the best was to obtain the relevant integer value from the array of objects that corresponds to this key?

Comment: Do you really need an array ? It might be better to just use an object not an array and do a key pair look up  so netAggregatedPosition = {} , netAggregatedPosition.2017_Q1 = _2017Q1} ..   and function createAggregate( key, value){
netAggregatedPosition[key] = value}

Comment: the question is the question

Comment: In my defense I can only say, I thought the questioner could consider a better way to achieve the  goal, that is why I provided a comment and not an answer.  Why do you have to use an array ?